# No VNC on Pi 3a Bookworm

Tags: vnc

I have a Pi 3A running PiOS Bookworm (32 bit).  I enabled ssh and vnc with raspi-config.  I checked the interface status in the graphical preferences tool, which shows that ssh and vnc are enabled.  I have rebooted several times.  NMAP shows that ssh is open at port 22, and that vnc is not open an any port.  Boot log reports: [  OK  ] Started vncserver-q11-serviced-service  - NVNC Server in Service Mode daemon.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Guess you didn't read the Bookworm news post, they recommend sticking with Bullseye for now if you need VNC:

> Similarly, the Wayland security model prevents traditional remote
> desktop access, and so a new VNC server, called wayvnc, is being used
> instead of RealVNC. This is a bit more restrictive in terms of the
> client applications which can connect to it — we have had good results
> with the TigerVNC client, available here.
>
> There is also currently a regression with the RealVNC server itself,
> which is still used in Bookworm on older Raspberry Pi models which
> don’t yet run Wayland. The 64-bit version works fine, but the 32-bit
> version is not currently compatible with Bookworm — we are waiting for
> an update from RealVNC. In the meantime, if you do need remote desktop
> access on a Raspberry Pi Zero, 1, 2, or 3, we recommend sticking with
> Bullseye for the time being.

https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/bookworm-the-new-version-of-raspberry-pi-os/

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix.. Just switch desktop to X11

https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=787FfnS0wbE

Night